# WPF application with edit box that can show english as well as japanese text data

Tags: wpf, localization, multilingual

We have WPF application built using .Net 4.5. The app has an edit box that needs to show data read from a file. When we have english text in the file, the content is shown correctly. When we load a file that has both english and Japanese text, the japanese text is rendered as garbage.
When we install multi-language pack, this issue is gone. I am trying to understand what is the best way to support this without needing to install multi-language pack.
We tried installing individual fonts and render data. That didn't work. Still garbage was shown.
I am trying to understand what is the trick that a multi-language pack installation does that we are missing.

Update:
Great link that talks about how Windows links various font files under common family name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx

Comment: Why is this tagged winforms...

Comment: This is a generic problem that applies to multiple UI stacks on windows. Plus I am being greedy trying to attract more people to look at this. :)

Comment: Don't do that. Just because the problem is generic does not mean that the solution will be. Most things are done very differently in WPF, and all the controls/UI elements are in a different part of the .NET framework.